# Server side computer speaks to all users?

Tags: php, real-time

I want users to be able to play a trivia game online. I have experience with real-time communications, but I need to store and pass out the data.
What I have now is run the same code on a "master" computer. Players send their data to this computer, and when the round is up, the master computer shares this data.

However, when the user with the master computer leaves, this becomes problematic. I was wondering if I could have this "master" computer run server side, at all times, and work with all clients at once.

Comment: Yes, the master computer must be connected at all times. Since the server is connected at all times, it makes sense for the server to run the master. You can implement this with simple periodic AJAX checks on each web client, but these days a WebSocket makes more sense, as it is faster, and more lightweight.

Comment: How would i go about setting up the websocket?

Comment: Node is popular as a WebSocket server, but I believe [you can do it with PHP as well](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=websocket+php). Also, [this looks relevant](http://socketo.me/).

Comment: Is there a way to host my site on a hosting provider server and still use these frameworks?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "hosting provider server". Do you mean using WebSockets on a shared host? Mostly the answer is no, you'll need a dedicated server, such as a VPS/cloud server. You could always build your site with AJAX whilst you are building a userbase, and swap to WebSockets when/if  you need to scale.

Comment: (That said, you can use a shared host for the web app and do WebSocket stuff with a third-party provider if you wish, such as Pusher).

Comment: First off, can i have a real-time, bi-directional server with ajax? Secondly, i have used the third party provider Pubnub in the past. The problem is running the "master" computer with this service. Is there a way to do that with pusher? thank you

Comment: "Can I have a real-time, bi-directional server with ajax". Not really: the client has to periodically check in for updates. It's inefficient, but it works, though it probably doesn't scale very well. I don't understand your second question. I think you might need to expand on what a master computer does, in the context you're using it.

Comment: I think the master computer is easiest to describe with a presence system. The current model has one user arrive. If it is the first and only user (which is difficult to determine) it will become the master computer. Then, all future people send their status to the master computer, and when changes occur, the master computer sends a message to all clients. However, when the client with the master computer leaves, it is problematic. I want to put the master computers code on a server that is always running.

Comment: Yes, if the first game player becomes a master, that's a problem, since if they leave the game, the game stops. Transfer that functionality to a server component (or have the first player be a dummy player that is always reserved by the server).

Comment: Would you have any suggestions on how I might write the server code? I  have used polling with Ajax with no success

Comment: Well, it depends in what way you were not successful. Each web client can use a JavaScript module to make periodic requests to the server, using a callback system such as `setTimeout()`. New events on the client side can be notified in this request, and in the response any new things the server wishes to push out can be notified. You generally need a database system to determine what server events have been notified to clients, so that the same event is not notified more than once. You need to check for HTTP failure too here, so that if a response fails an event will be notified again.

Comment: my struggle is that when a user contacts the master server, the server can only respond to THAT user. I would like it to send a message to all online users.

Comment: In the AJAX system I outlined, all users will in due course make a request to the server, since they are all running JavaScript timers. When they do make that request, you can add any messages that are pending for that user, in the response.